# Is there a way I can link a selected record in a subform to a textbox in the form?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create a form where I have a section with text boxes and a subform displaying all the data in the table, I've created the text boxes and subform and managed to display the data. However I am trying to make it so whenever I select the a record in the subform, the textboxes get changed to the currently selected record.

I have managed to make it work using a list box, however a list box cannot be edited.

I have included screenshots to better show what I am trying to do.

[what I am trying to do with the subform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAry2.png)

[what I have managed to with the listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wSnV.png)

Comment: Ms-Access split forms are exactly for this purpose; do you have to use the old version of MsAccess?

Comment: @tinazmu split forms completely solved my issue, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to roll your own "split form" here.  See "Create a split form" at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-split-form-e8eb0efb-2fa6-4315-9d4b-86e79a1fbe1e

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Private Sub Form_Current() on the subform.
There you update the buttons in the main form.